# How to add info from search for few line above, using sed,awk or similar

Tags: awk, sed

Using sed, awk or similar
I've a file.xml like below, i want put the value from mytag to the tagxpto exactly before

```
    <tagxpto field= />
    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    <mytag value="SUB1-SUB2" />
    <tagxpto field= />
    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    <mytag value="SUB3-SUB4" />
    <tagxpto field= />
    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    <mytag value="SUB5-SUB6" />
    [..]
```

**Expected:**

```
    <tagxpto field="SUB1-SUB2" />
    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    <mytag value="SUB1-SUB2" />
    <tagxpto field=SUB3-SUB4 />
    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    <mytag value="SUB3-SUB4" />
    <tagxpto field=SUB5-SUB6 />
    <tag1>    
    <tag2>    
    <mytag value="SUB5-SUB6" /> 
    [..]
```

Can you help me how to do this task?

Comment: the input xml is invalid, wrong attributes `field= `

Comment: it's only example.. have another attribute name..

Comment: won't go with invalid structure, good luck

Comment: It's only an example..consider being a not xml file. from the example,  i want put the output from value= to field= exactly before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/tagxpto/{:a;N;/mytag/!ba;s/=(.*("[^"]*"))/=\2\1/}' file
```

Gather up lines from `tagxpto` to `mytag` then substitute the required string using backreferences.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if ( match($0,/^\s*<mytag\s*value=("[^"]*")/,a) ) {
        tags[++myCnt] = a[1]
    }
    next
}
match($0,/^(\s*<tagxpto\s*field=)(.*\/>)/,a) {
    $0 = a[1] tags[++xptoCnt] a[2]
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
    <tagxpto field="SUB1-SUB2" />
    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    <mytag value="SUB1-SUB2" />
    <tagxpto field="SUB3-SUB4" />
    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    <mytag value="SUB3-SUB4" />
    <tagxpto field="SUB5-SUB6" />
    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    <mytag value="SUB5-SUB6" />
```

Note that your posted expected output sometimes adds the field within quotes and sometimes not with no explanation of when to include the quotes and when not so I've assumed that you always want it in quotes, it's a trivial tweak if you don't, e.g. change the capture group `("[^"]*")` to `"([^"]*)"`

Comment: I've strange behavior, Your 'awk' works fine in cygwin , but not works in redhat, do you have idea why?

Comment: cygwin uses GNU awk  like the answer states is required. Are you using GNU awk on "redhat"? Check `awk --version`

Answer (score 0):

try one more approach with awk, reading Input_file single time only.

```
awk '/<tagxpto field/ && val2{sub(/= /,"="val2,val1);print val1 ORS val;val1=$0;val=val2=""} NR==1{val1=$0;next} {val=val?val ORS $0:$0} /<mytag value/{match($0,/".*"/);val2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)} END{sub(/= /,"="val2,val1);print val1 ORS val}'   Input_file
```

Will add it's non-one liner form and explanation too within sometime too.

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk '/<tagxpto field/ && val2{
                                sub(/= /,"="val2,val1);
                                print val1 ORS val;
                                val1=$0;
                                val=val2=""
                             }
    NR==1{
                val1=$0;
                next
         }
         {
                val=val?val ORS $0:$0
         }
    /<mytag value/{
                        match($0,/".*"/);
                        val2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                  }
    END{
        sub(/= /,"="val2,val1);
        print val1 ORS val
       }
    '    Input_file
```